# Unable to run Simple "Hello World!" Java Program when internet is down

Tags: java

Don't know how to put this out, but the issue is continuously producing. I wrote a simple printing "Hello World!". It runs normally when the internet is connected or I am totally offline from any source of the network.

But If I disable my internet(Still connected to LAN with static IP) my program does not run (It is stuck i.e. no class is loaded yet)(No errors thrown). As soon as I start my internet connection, the program gets executed successfully. I am unable to understand this behavior.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!!");
    }
}
```

Given is code snippet.

Comment: How you execute the code?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer To compile : javac App.java  and to run : java App

Comment: Are you using any online compiler ? Better to install `jdk` to your local machine.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Yes I have jdk1.8 on my local

Comment: Which Java? Run `java --version` and add the result to your question. Recent versions of Oracle Java verify their license online, so that may be the reason.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I agree but as I said when I am totally offline code run with no issue.

Comment: That could be because it only tries to verify it if it sees that a connection exists. Again, please add the required information to your question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic below is information needed : openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-2~14.04-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: also share the classpath. take a thread dump and check where the thread is blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Newer versions of java verify their license online, as the internet was disabled, it blocks the program.